# How to get value from date filter input field with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, input

There is a date filter with input fields and drop-down datepicker like on below image[image: date filter image]

I want to get current value of, for example, "From" input field (expected output = `"03/13/2013"`). So for following element's code

```
<div class="input-group date" id="inputValidFrom">
        <input name="validFrom" class="form-control" id="inputValidFromValue" required="" type="text"> </input>
```

I use `Python's` lines:

```
>>>from selenium import webdriver
>>>driver = webdriver.Ie()
>>>input = driver.get_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="validFrom"]')
>>>input.text # returns empty string
''
>>>input.get_attribute('value') # also returns ''
''
>>>input.value_of_css_property('text') # returns again just empty string
''
```

Who knows the way how to get this input field box property?

Comment: where is set "From" element?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the IE-Driver with XPath. 
Try writing the attribute name in lower case.
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-xpath

Comment: I use lower case attributes in xpaths and `selenium` actually can "find" element despite of applied web driver, but I can't get text value of element...

Comment: Ok, that was a bad guess. Did you try the drivers for firefox or chrome? Do they behave the same way?

Comment: ...and that was good guess) I checked `Chrome` and `FireFox` - `a.get_attribute('value')` method works! So seems that it's just `IE` issue... And that's bad because `IE` is target browser and I should use only it

Comment: The input is type="text" and displays a date-picker. So there could be some JS-magic involved. Can you reveal more parts of the page?